# Video not loading with VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, html5-video

I am working with Vue.js 2 and Laravel and have been trying to load a video from a local folder of my project without success.

Vue-loader plugin is correctly installed and added in my webpack.config.js as specified on the docs: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/#manual-setup

I have tried the most simple way.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
      <source src="/storage/videos/landing.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
</template>
```

I have also tried with a different approach as suggested on another stackoverflow question by dinamically updating the src attribute when the component is mounted.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <video ref="videoRef" src="" autoplay muted loop id="myVideo"></video>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted: function() {
    this.$refs.videoRef.src =
      "/storage/videos/landing.mp4";
  }
};
</script>
```

None of those have worked tho.

Im quite sure the problem lies in Vue not resolving the video route properly since I have tried to use a dummy video link from the web and it is working absolutely fine.

Firefox is also giving me some clues.

[image]

However, Im not sure about what the problem is or how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

PS: I have triple checked the route specified and it definitely exists in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Either you load your video with an es module import, **your loader has to be able to import mp4**, and you put that in the src

```
import video from 'path/to/video/a.mp4'
```

and in your component you do

```
<video :src="video">
```

**PS** make sure that the imported video is then defined in your data function.

Or you can use it like your doing with `src="path/to/folder"` and try to understand where that path is pointing at through your network tab, and put the video in the right folder based on that.

Comment: There is something wrong with my loader :(. Im getting the following error when compiling: "Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders"

Comment: yea, that's what I said in bold.

Comment: Do I need to specify that it has to be able to import mp4 somewhere? I thought installing the loader and referencing it on the webpack config was enough.

Comment: You need to update your vue.config.js with the file loader update